# Trust a Certificate Authority in Java

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, ssl-certificate, keystore

I'm trying to consume some webservices in my Spring boot Applications, I got this error in swagger when I try to execute my request, I tried to search for the url of the webservices in a browser (https://ip:port) then I got a security error telling me that the certificate authority is not recognized "SEC_ERROR_UNKOWN_ISSUER".. I thought that the problem is coming from there.
I tried to export the certificate from the browser and to import it in my cacerts but it didn't work.. Could a problem in my code be the cause of this error?

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-11-16T08:11:16.189+00:00",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "I/O error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target",
  "path": "***"
}
```

Comment: what certificate did you add to your cacerts? The server cert or the CA cert?

Comment: I added the CA cert

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I might be late with the answer but I am anyways going to post it here because I am pretty sure someone will need it in the future.

After hours of searching for the answer I found the reason. I haven't imported self-signed root CA certificate into the java's cacerts keystore and therefore, I kept on getting the same exception.

Command to add root CA to the cacerts keystore from one of the stackoverflow answers.

```
keytool -import -alias mycert -keystore  "<<your-JAVA_HOME-directory>>\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file mycert.cer
```

However, it did not work for me and I had to point it to
`keytool -import -alias mycert -keystore  "<<your-JAVA_HOME-directory>>\lib\security\cacerts" -file mycert.cer` to my jdk instead of jre folder.

Default password of the keystore is "changeit"